# Non-elegant chipped ellipses with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qtgui

I am drawing an ellipse around a target. However the ellipses are not joined and elegant. By elegant I mean they are not smooth. this is what the ellipse around the image looks like

Notice the circle is not smooth and has roughness I would like to make it a smooth circle/ellipse. Any suggestions on how I could do that ? This is currently how I am doing the ellipses.

```
QPainter painter(target);

QPen pen;
pen.setColor(Qt::red);
pen.setWidth(4);
pen.setStyle( Qt::SolidLine);
pen.setCapStyle(Qt::SquareCap);
pen.setJoinStyle(Qt::BevelJoin);
painter.setPen(pen);

QRegion r(QRect(0, 0, 50, 50), QRegion::Ellipse); 
painter.setClipRegion(r);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, source);
painter.drawEllipse(QRect(1, 1, 49, 49));
```

Comment: For reference: you're talking about "anti-aliasing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable antialiasing:

```
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a call to

```
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing)
```

before drawing.

Note also that region-based clipping *might not be antialiased*, so you'd better just draw the parts you're interested in (f.i. by drawing an ellipse with a textured QBrush).

Comment: This is actually a better answer at least for Qt 3.4 where I tested this. The clipping mask is not anti-aliased.